# How to reverse list order in Python and stop yield upon return of None?

Tags: python

I am generating pagination links which I suspect exists with Python 3.x:

```
start_urls = [
    'https://...',
    'https://...' # list full of URLs
]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = url,
            meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]},
            callback=self.parse,
        )

def parse(self, response):
    for i in range(1, 6):
        url = response.url + '&pn='+str(i)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):

        # check if no results page
        if response.xpath('//*[@id="searchList"]/div[1]').extract_first():
            self.logger.info('No results found on  %s', response.url)
            return None
        ...
```

Those URLs will be processed by scrapy in parse_item. Now there are 2 problems:

1. The order is reverse and I do not understand why. It will request pagen umbers: 5,4,3,2,1 instead of 1,2,3,4,5
2. If the no results are found on page 1, the entire series could be stoped. Parse Item returns already "None", but the I guess I need to adapt the method "parse" to exit the for loop and continue. How?

Answer (score 1):

The `scrapy.Request` you generate are running in parallel - In other words, there is guarantee for the order how you get the response as it depends on the server.

If some of the requests, depends on the response of of a request, you should yield those requests in its parse callback.

For example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    url = response.url + '&pn='+str(1)
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_item, cb_kwargs=dict(page=1, base_url=response.url))
                             

def parse_item(self, response,page, base_url):
        # check if no results page
        if response.xpath('//*[@id="searchList"]/div[1]').extract_first():
            if page < 6:
                url = base_url + '&pn='+str(page+1)
                yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_item, cb_kwargs=dict(base_url=base_url,page=page+1))
        else:
            # your code
            yield ...
```

Comment: Not sure if I explained it good enough as I don't understand the reasoning behind your code. The "no results check" is there to identify if the search result is empty. In this case do not continue to go to page2,3.. Just go to those pages if smaller then 6. In case it is a page to parse, parse_item will extract all search results from it after the ... Then yield it and proceed to the next page. If your code provides that, I do not understand it.

Comment: Have you tried it? The point is to generate the request only when you know it is valid request.

Comment: It is getting clearer now. I implemented it and the only thing that seems wrong is the fact that it will not echchange the page number but append it: &pn=1&pn=2. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Updated - you should also move the base_url to parse_item and not relying on response.url

Comment: Sorry, but I still can not get it to work. For clarification I updated the question where I am caling the parse method while cycling through a list of URLs. How to mo e the base_url to parse_item? I thought that is the whole point of the parse function to generate those paginated urls?

Comment: OK, I have it running now (fixed minor changes in my code I saw in yours) with one disadvantage. Scrapy will make two requests for the same page but parse only one. They are identical: example.htm and example.htm?pn=1 Only the later one gets parsed but both get requested. I tried to save this one request but without luck. Do you see a possibility?

Comment: Use `page=2` instead of `page=1` when you yield the request in `parse`

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, in that case page no 2 will not get parsed.

Comment: I am experiencing some kind of memory leak since deploying this spider. Tried to find the cause and believe that the cb_kwargs parameter is the problem while following this help: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html 
Is there something I need to release to stop the memory leak?